# Magmi import doesn't update URL key

Tags: product-attribute, ce-1.9.1.0, magmi

I have imported some products and later needed to change the URL keys so I have prepared a CSV which contain SKUs and the new url keys (ie: sku,url_key) . But after successfully import (Update existing items only,skip new ones) and check with backend product URL keys but they are not changed , I have re index them all but still the same, then I have imported the same CSV file using advanced dataflow profiles and it is working fine URL keys changed as per the CSV by using dataflow profiles . So can someone explain me why this is happening ?

regards
chamal

Answer (score 0):

After completion of your import go to your database and truncate table"core_url_rewrites". when table is truncated,reindex urls through admin panel. your url key will be updated.